# Why can't I use a lambda as a comparator for a set defined in a class?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

This is fairly standard and works fine:

```
#include <set>

auto cmp = [](int a, int b) { return a > b; };
using stype = std::set<int, decltype(cmp)>;

stype mySet(cmp);
```

But why can't I do this?

```
#include <set>

auto cmp = [](int a, int b) { return a > b; };
using stype = std::set<int, decltype(cmp)>;

struct foo {
    stype mySet(cmp);
};
```

This fails with `Unknown type name 'cmp'` (in XCode 5.1.1, compiling for Mac using llvm, in case it's relevant.)

What is the reason for this error, and how can I fix / work around it? Do I have to avoid using a lambda for this purpose, and if so, why?

My actual code has several classes that store objects of type `stype::iterator` to point to items inside `foo::mySet`, so I do want to declare `stype` outside the struct.

Comment: Nothing to do with lambdas. You just can't initialize nonstatic class members that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-static data member initializer must be a *brace-or-equal-initializer*. The following should work:

```
stype mySet {cmp};
stype mySet = stype(cmp);
```

However, `stype mySet(cmp);` is parsed as declaring a member *function* named `mySet` that returns `stype` and takes an unnamed argument of type `cmp`, hence the error.

Comment: `= cmp;` won't work. That constructor is `explicit`.

Comment: @T.C. Whoops, you're right, I wasn't paying attention to what `stype` is.

Comment: Thanks for answering what turned out to be a fairly stupid question! Much appreciated.